# window problem when choosing save location

Tags: release-loki, window-management

When I try to save/download a file and choose a save location that is different from the default one, I cannot finish the operation because the window lacks an OK or even Cancel button. See here:

[image]

Is this a bug (which I think it is) or is there any good reason behind it?

Comment: Maybe the same problem I was having, danrabbit directed me to a solution:
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/buttons-are-missing-in-the-file-chooser-dialog-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 0):

Not really helping ... but I am on the same boat, here !

However, I did not notice that I have this problem, on an old profile which has been used with many distro (*Freya*, *Gnome* etc). With a brand new *Loki* user profile, I have no problem and I can see the footer of the dialog windows with the *OK* and *Cancel* buttons.

If some would know, how to reset this configuration for that user I would be grateful. I already tried the *restore default parameters* button from the *Parameters => About* Window.

Comment: This was indeed a duplicate and the solution  given there, worked !