# Why I am not getting extract button in archive manager?

Tags: release-loki, applications, window-management

I have elementary OS Loki, many time I do not get some buttons in dialogue boxes ( like 'Save', 'OK', 'Extract' ). How do I fix this ?

[image: Screenshot 1 is showing Archive manager]

[image: Can not see Extract button]

Comment: Try this:
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/buttons-are-missing-in-the-file-chooser-dialog-what-should-i-do