# Unable to select files from file manager in eos whe uploading,saving, or opening a file

Tags: pantheon-files

I am using 16.04 base(loki) and the file manager doesn't show buttons to select/save/upload files. For instance - 

Example 1. when I start writing a new text file and then save it using Ctrl+S I am unable to select a name for it as there should be on top bar of file manager.

  Example 2. When I try to select a file in an application there's no open button it just shows list of files without any button to select a particular file. Some fm support double click to select a file, even that doesn't work here 
see the screenshots[image: When saving a file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to the previously reported bug 1506069 on launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1506069).

Does http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/buttons-are-missing-in-the-file-chooser-dialog-what-should-i-do solve your problem?

Comment: thanks, the second link did work. I simply executed the from that link in the terminal as ->
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader': <0>, 'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close:menu,maximize'>}"

Comment: Thank you, you save my day. Any @lawk you should accept this as the answer.