# Can't save images in any browser

Tags: chromium

I cant figure this out for the life of me, but it seems impossible to save an image using any browser.

I am very very new to linux, but I will try to provide any sort of helpful information I can.

This is what I see when I try an save an image to any file folder:
[image]

There is no save button, as far as I can tell, and the only thing I can do is hit escape to get out of the save feature.

Any help would be great!

Comment: What happens when you right click the image and choose the option "save image as"

Comment: The image that I posted is what happens when I choose that option

Comment: ok, and what happens when you use a different browser such as chromium or firefox?

Comment: I tried with Chromium, Chrome, and Firefox and I get the same result :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your theme to default and restart. This happened to me when messing around with a theme. (Btw: which theme is that?)

Try this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader': <0>, 'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close:menu,maximize'>}"
```

(from this question: [Buttons are missing in the file chooser dialog. What should I do?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/buttons-are-missing-in-the-file-chooser-dialog-what-should-i-do))

Comment: Tried that and still nothing :( Also it is the theme is https://github.com/eti0/arc-grey-theme

Comment: Is everything up-to.date? Have you restarted? I updated, my answer, try that command.

Comment: THANK YOU! The command you added worked. You are a legend :)

Comment: still works in 2018, use this people