# File Dialogue Doesn't Work

Tags: release-loki, applications, release-juno

On Loki I have the same problem with several applications which involve a file dialogue. When I select a file there is no way to 'Save', as there is no button to click, [Enter] doesn't work and (double-)left-click doesn't work. Could you look at the picture below and tell me whether there is a button missing from this standard file dialogue? Perhaps a header bar is missing that should have Save, Cancel and Search buttons.
[image]

Comment: Your file dialog looks not at all like the elementary theme but more like Adwaita or something.

This question is probably a duplicate of https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/buttons-are-missing-in-the-file-chooser-dialog-what-should-i-do

It seems to me that problem can be caused by using Gnome Tweaks on elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

'Pantheon-files' had no header bar so no 'Cancel', 'Save' or 'Search' buttons! I removed 'pantheon-files' and installed 'Nautilus' which fixed it. I have since installed Juno - which had the same problem and the same solution.

Comment: Something you did is causing that. Pantheon-files doesn't look like that by default. There must be some weird config file in your /home directory causing that. If you create a new user it may go back to normal.

Comment: Sounds likely, but if I created a new user I would obviously want to copy all my files in - bringing the guilty file with them. Perhaps someone who knows something about pantheon-files would let me know what configuration files it uses so I can avoid overwriting them.