# Impossible to Download ISO - JUNO Beta

Tags: iso

When I try to (simple) download it, I just get a file manager screen - no clue about what I'm supposed to do. Click or [Enter] don't do anything.

[image]

The other option "Magnet Link" says it requires software installation. There is no mention of it in the AppStore or the installation advice here https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation

Answer (score 1):

To download using the magnet link you need an app like qBitorrent. You can easily install it with `sudo apt install qbitorrent`.

Regarding your other issue. It's probably related to your web browser. You should try with another one.

Comment: I've installed that and it works. Seems odd that eOS has recommended a method that uses a package that isn't installed by default in eOS.  I rather doubt that it is related to Firefox as I have used it to download all sorts of things on several other OSs.

Comment: Well you can use Epiphany. And btw, there's a stable Juno release that you might want to consider instead of the beta version.

Comment: Now you mention it I have spotted that the 'Beta' has gone from the name.  It's not a browser problem, it's the file dialogue. I have the same problem with several applications which use it. When I select a file there is no way to 'Save', as there is no button to click, [Enter] doesn't work and (double-)left-click doesn't work. That's not relevant to this question so I've put the details here https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/file-dialogue-doesnt-work